# Solve $\int \frac{(\sin x)^2}{a+b\cos x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$\dfrac{1-\cos^2x}{a+b\cos x}=A+B\cos x+\dfrac C{a+b\cos x}$$

Find $A,B,C$  by comparing the coefficients of $\cos^0x,\cos x,\cos^2x$

For $$\int\dfrac{dx}{a+b\cos x}$$

use Weierstrass Substitution, $\cos2y=\dfrac{1-\tan^2y}{1+\tan^2y}$

Answer (score 2):

I have a better hint.

You have $$\int\ \frac{\sin(x)\ \sin(x)\ \text{d}x}{a + b\cos(x)}$$

Use $t = \cos(x)$ so then $\text{d}t = -\sin(x)\ \text{d}x$ and you got already a half of the numerator.

Now $\sin(x) = \sqrt{1 - t^2}$ so then your integral becomes

$$ — \int\ \frac{\sqrt{1 - t^2}\ \text{d}t}{a + bt}$$

Which you can solve.

Comment: I tried it before, but I don't know how to solve this, I think it's more easy with trigonometrics functions, I always run away from square functions. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Rafael The standard technique for solving integrals with square-roots of quadratics is the [method of Euler substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). The method shows that these integrals are nothing to be afraid of. In fact, you should run toward them! :)